# How to show in view (Angular) associated model data (from Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have problem with expressions associated data. I have **order** and parent model **meal**. Meal has one order. Order has: id of meal and status. `order.status` is display proper, but `order.meal.name` doesn't. This is my rails controller:

```
def index
  respond_with current_user.orders
end
```

In that way I try display data in Angular:

```
 <tbody ng-repeat="order in orders | orderBy: '-cost' | filter:activeOrder">
    <tr>
      <td>{{order.id}}</td>
      <td>{{order.meal.name}}</td>
      <td>{{order.meal.cost}}</td>
      <td>{{order.status}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Create order in Angular:

```
orders.create({
  meal_id: $scope.meal.id,
  status: "ordered",
});
```

And create in Rails:

```
def create
    order = meal.create_order(order_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))
    respond_with order
end
```

What can be wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Order** model I've wrote this code:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  super(options.merge(include: :meal))
end
```

And now it working!

Answer (score 0):

```
 def index
  temp_array = Array.new
  current_user.orders.each do |order|
  temp_hash = Hash.new
  temp_hash[:order] = order
  temp_hash[:meal] = order.meal
  temp_array << temp_hash
  end

   respond_with temp_array.to_json
 end


<tbody ng-repeat="order in orders | orderBy: '-cost' | filter:activeOrder">
<tr>
  <td>{{order.order.id}}</td>
  <td>{{order.meal.name}}</td>
  <td>{{order.meal.cost}}</td>
  <td>{{order.status}}</td>
</tr>
```

Angular can can't access the model associations so you manually pass the value to show

Comment: I've changed code with your advice but still it doesn't work

Comment: `[{id: 2, meal_id: 2, status: "ordered", created_at: "2016-02-24T10:55:02.189Z",…},…]` but when I've changed code, I can't save data in DB

Comment: I've found solution. Thanks for your help!